# CSS flexbox. Можно ли изменить размер изображения?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Все четыре изображения большого размера.

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.3ders.org/images/slug-traq-3d-printed-test-1.png" alt="">
<img src="https://www.3ders.org/images/slug-traq-3d-printed-test-1.png" alt="">
<img src="https://www.3ders.org/images/slug-traq-3d-printed-test-1.png" alt="">
<img src="https://www.3ders.org/images/slug-traq-3d-printed-test-1.png" alt="">
```

Вопрос такой. Можно ли средствами лишь flexbox, без применения к изображениям width и тп, изменить размер изображения?
Дело в том, что по стандарту изображения выстариваются одну линию и не подгоняются под ширину страницы. Хотелось бы чтобы их ширина подгонялась под страницу, а высота определялась автоматически. Оборнуть это дело в контейнер типа div нельзя. Не знаю почему, такова задача =(

---

нашел еще column-fill, но он не относится к flexbox на прямую. Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: вот пример      https://codepen.io/sbelialov/pen/NyMGPY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Одними лишь средствами flexbox, без применения к изображениям width и т.п. изменить ширину изображения не получится (а высоту получится). У самого изображения есть свои изначальные размеры. Эти размеры применяются если в стилях не заданы другие размеры.

Если у родительского компонента задать `height: 100%;` тогда изображения автоматически смогут подстраиваться по высоте. Но с шириной так не получится.

Могу посоветовать лишь использовать у изображений `width`. Например, так:

```
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; // позволяет дочерним компонентам растягиваться на всю высоту
}
img {
   width: calc(100% / 4);
  // object-fit: cover; // если хотите, чтобы чтобы изображение масштабировалась пропорционально 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  display:flex;
  align-items:flex-start;
}
img{
  flex:1 1 auto;
  /*Ширина тут чисто символическая, для корректной работы flexBox*/
  width:10px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://bm.img.com.ua/nxs/img/prikol/images/large/1/2/308321_879389.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="http://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/3-6.png" alt="" />
<img src="http://www.bugaga.ru/uploads/posts/2016-08/1471555196_subbota-25.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="http://www.prikol.ru/wp-content/gallery/october-2017/kartinki-04102017-001.jpg" alt="" />
```